# What is the solution to host external Internet pages now?

Tags: sharepoint-online, m365

We have been looking for ways to host sites externally, but haven't found a method with M365 SharePoint Online yet.

Power Pages aren't very editor-friendly and too limited in functionality for us to utilize.
In on-prem versions of SharePoint, you could do things like 'extend web' to put the site collection into a accessible location available to the Internet, but that functionality no longer exists with the cloud-hosted M365 solution.

So what are people using these days to host content externally on the Internet for the public?  We need to push data (lists/files) to this external site, and haven't found a solution yet - surprising everyone here.

Thoughts?

Comment: For SharePoint online, this feature is not yet available. Unlike on-premise, many functions can be expanded, and data security must be considered first. To address your concern about the situation, we’d suggest you go to feedback on this issue, this is the best platform to let us hear from you and make our products and services better for you and others. The more votes, the easier it is to be seen. https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472